# N-Ary Versions of Tuple Functions

Tags: haskell

Is there a library that has n-ary versions of tuple functions like `first`, `***`, etc, through Template Haskell (or using some other method).

Ideally I would like to able to say

```
$(select 3 [0, 1])
```

which we make the lambda

```
\(x, y, z) -> (x, y)
```

and for a generic `***` for functions

```
$(tapply 3 [(0, "f"), (1, "g"), (2, "h")])
```

which would make the lambda

```
\f g h (x, y, z) -> (f x, g y, h z)
```

Other n-ary functions would also be nice, but those are the two I need currently.

Answer (score 3):

Here is [an example](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Template_Haskell#Select_from_a_tuple) to achieve this using Template Haskell.

Answer (score 3):

The [tuple](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/tuple) library provides lots of these sorts of functions.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, I'd say you want to use a proper ADT instead, and libraries like [bifunctor](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/bifunctors), or, if it gets more complex than that, a proper [generics](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Libraries_and_tools/Generic_programming) library. (That link could be more up to date... if in doubt, and you don't have especially high performance requirements, just use [SYB](http://www.cs.uu.nl/wiki/GenericProgramming/SYB))