# Haskell Performing fst on a 3 part tuple

Tags: haskell

I have the following Haskell tuple:

```
       [("string",1,1)]
```

I need to extract the first element of this, obviously using 'fst' wont work here as there are 3 components.

What is the best method to use? [sel](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/tuple/0.2.0.1/doc/html/Data-Tuple-Select.html) ?

Comment: Possible dupe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5844347/haskell-accessing-a-specific-element-in-a-tuple.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You could just type your own function (we will use pattern matching) for this:

```
fst3 :: (a, b, c) -> a
fst3 (x, _, _) = x
```

and you use it like:

```
fst3 ("string", 1, 1)
```

Comment: @user2214957 If you don't know (I see you are new user): When you decide which answer you like the most, you should accept it as best/correct answer.

Answer (score 9):

`sel` can be used in the following manner:

```
$ cabal install tuple
$ ghci
>>> :m +Data.Tuple.Select
>>> sel1 ("string",1,1)
"string"
```

It works like any other function with `map`

```
>>> map sel1 [("One",1,0),("Two",2,0),("Three",3,0)]
["One","Two","Three"]
```

The main advantage is that it works for a bigger tuple

```
>>> sel1 ("string",1,1,1)
"string"
```

as well as the standard tuple

```
>>> sel1 ("string",1)
"string"
```

hence there is no need of handling them separately.

---

Some more examples:

```
>>> map sel2 [("One",1,0),("Two",2,0),("Three",3,0)]
[1,2,3]
(0.06 secs, 4332272 bytes)
>>> map sel3 [("One",1,0),("Two",2,0),("Three",3,0)]
[0,0,0]
(0.01 secs, 2140016 bytes)
>>> map sel4 [("One",1,0),("Two",2,0),("Three",3,0)]

<interactive>:6:5:
.... error
```

Comment: yes it is, for all tuple of size equal of less than 15 (as sel15 is defined but no sel16).

Comment: this limitation is due to ghc tupe limitation for more information see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2978389/haskell-tuple-size-limit

Comment: I wouldn't consider `tuple` dead, just stable.

Comment: Ok, I'd like to say no more maintained, Anyway I'm going to remove my consideration as it appears to be incorrect.

Comment: Running `cabal install tuple` today (2021) gives me
_Warning: You asked to install executables, but there are no executables in
target: tuple. Perhaps you want to use --lib to install libraries instead._

Answer (score 5):

You can also use the 
[lens](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens) package:

```
> import Control.Lens
> Prelude Control.Lens> view _1 (1,2)  -- Or (1,2) ^. _1
1
> Prelude Control.Lens> view _1 (1,2,3) -- Or (1,2,3) ^. _1
1
> Prelude Control.Lens> view _1 (1,2,3,4) -- Or (1,2,3,4) ^. _1
1
> Prelude Control.Lens> view _1 (1,2,3,4,5) -- Or (1,2,3,4,5) ^. _1
1
```

This works for more than just the first element

```
> import Control.Lens
> Prelude Control.Lens> view _2 (1,2)  -- Or (1,2) ^. _2
2
> Prelude Control.Lens> view _3 (1,2,3) -- Or (1,2,3) ^. _3
3
> Prelude Control.Lens> view _4 (1,2,3,4) -- Or (1,2,3,4) ^. _4
4
> Prelude Control.Lens> view _5 (1,2,3,4,5) -- Or (1,2,3,4,5) ^. _5
5
```

I also wrote an answer to a similar question that covers more than just tuples:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/23860744/128583

Answer (score 4):

I would just define a function

```
fst3 :: (a,b,c) -> a
fst3 (x,_,_) = x
```

That's easy to understand and doesn't have a weird type (the type of `sel1` is `Sel1 a b => a -> b` which may be confusing)

Or you could extract the value which you're interested in via patternmatching as in `[x | (x,_,_) <- myThreeTupleList`.

Finally, the best solution is to use a more structured data type! Surely, the string and the two ints carry more meaning and it's a good idea to encode that somehow...

Comment: @Martinsos: It's a pretty common name for this function; see for instance the [MissingH package](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/MissingH/1.1.1.0/doc/html/Data-Tuple-Utils.html). In fact, I think was supposed to be added to Data.Tuple in 2008: see [this message on the libraries mailing list](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.haskell.libraries/8841).

Answer (score 3):

You could do this:

```
Prelude> let [(a,_,_)]=[("string",1,1)]
Prelude> a
"string"
```