# reaching elements of tuple by index number in Haskell

Tags: haskell, tuples

how to reach elements of tuple by giving the index number ? Or is there any other similar way to do it?
 For example i have a tuple with eight element and i want to reach its 6th element

Comment: Related (maybe duplicate) [Haskell - Accessing a Specific Element in a Tuple](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5844347/126916)

Comment: The conventional wisdom is that if you have an 8 element tuple, it should be a datatype.

Answer (score 3):

One method is to use the 
[lens](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens) package.

```
> import Control.Lens
> Prelude Control.Lens> view _1 (1,2)
1
> Prelude Control.Lens> view _2 (1,2,3)
2
> Prelude Control.Lens> view _3 (1,2,3,4)
3
> Prelude Control.Lens> view _4 (1,2,3,4,5)
4
```

The `_?` operators are only defined up to `_9` but it is rather easy to define more if needed.